# Output the sum of the ASCII values for each character of the input in Python

Tags: python, loops, input, sum, ascii

I can't find a way to sum the ASCII numerical values, I keep getting errors.

This is my code:

```
str = input("Enter your name: ")
for c in str:
    print("The ASCII value for ", c, "is", ord(c))
```

I deleted the part that was summing it because it was wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have enough information. What errors are you getting? If the summation code is what you are having trouble with, posting that might help.

Comment: @Viper: Cold you show how you were doing the summing? It would help to point out where you made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the following using built-in `sum` and list comprehensions. As a good practice, remember not to define variables with built-in types or functions names (str).

```
name = input("Enter your name: ") 
for c in name: 
  print("The ASCII value for ", c, "is", ord(c))
print("The total sum is: ",sum([ord(c) for c in name]))
```